# Hide/Show fields with dynamic IDs (NodeJS, Mongoose, Express, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have a forEach loop which displays menus for different restaurants when the restaurant icon is clicked.  The restaurant icons and the number of restaurants/menus is unknown and each is created with a dynamic ID, e.g. menu-0, menu-1, menu-2 etc.

When one restaurant icon is clicked, all the others should be hidden.  Currently I have the below Javascript to show/hide the menus; while this is working, I'm working for a way to make it more dynamic/efficient, rather than a static list, given the number of menus is unknown.

````
let menu0 = document.getElementById('menu-0');
let menuIcon1 = document.getElementById('menu-icon-1');
let menu1 = document.getElementById('menu-1');
let menuIcon2 = document.getElementById('menu-icon-2');
let menu2 = document.getElementById('menu-2');
let menuIcon3 = document.getElementById('menu-icon-3');
let menu3 = document.getElementById('menu-3');
let menuIcon4 = document.getElementById('menu-icon-4');
let menu4 = document.getElementById('menu-4');

$('#menu-icon-0').on('click', function(e) {
    if (menu0.style.display = 'none') {
        menu0.style.display = 'block';
        menuIcon0.style.border = '5px solid #2541B2';

        menuIcon1.style.border = 'none';
        menu1.style.display = 'none';
        menuIcon2.style.border = 'none';
        menu2.style.display = 'none';
        menuIcon3.style.border = 'none';
        menu3.style.display = 'none';
        menuIcon4.style.border = 'none';
        menu4.style.display = 'none';
    }
})

$('#menu-icon-1').on('click', function(e) {
    if (menu1.style.display = 'none') {
        menu1.style.display = 'block';
        menuIcon1.style.border = '5px solid #2541B2';
        
        menuIcon0.style.border = 'none';
        menu0.style.display = 'none';
        menuIcon2.style.border = 'none';
        menu2.style.display = 'none';
        menuIcon3.style.border = 'none';
        menu3.style.display = 'none';
        menuIcon4.style.border = 'none';
        menu4.style.display = 'none';
    }
})```
````

Answer (score 0):

from my experience you have to add custom class to your dynamic elements , then you can set the click on the class name for example, and inside the click you search for all elements that have this class, make for loop and compare the id of element with the clicked view id if not equals you should hide the boarder.

Answer (score 0):

you are using jquery right? so  all this can be boiled down to

```
$('#menu-icon-0').on('click', function(e) {

  $('#menu-icon-0').toggle()
}
```

Comment: Yes appreciate I could use toggle instead of display block/none, but the key question I have is how to handle it for an unknown number of records, hence I don't think this answers the question. But thanks for response.

Comment: my bad I got sidetracked you can use a class for that. 
  $('.click-me').on('click', function(e) {

  e.target.toggle()
}